# Visual Studio Desktop Application with AWS Profile

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this working fine in DEV.  I can upload images to S3 for AWS. It is a desktop application that is using an AWS profile that I setup in the AWS explorer in Visual Studio (I called the profile "production").  Again, that works fine.  My App.config has this line.

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="production" />
```

Wen I put the application on a production machine, I get the a credential error. Why doesn't it see my credentials on the production machine?  Shouldn't the come over when I publish the application?  What do I have to do to bring the profile information to production?  Thank you.

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to find credentials 

Exception 1 of 4: 
System.ArgumentException: App.config does not contain credentials information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey or AWSProfileName. 
 at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor(String profileName, String profilesLocation) 
 at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentAWSCredentials..ctor() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.b__1() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean fallbackToAnonymous) 

Exception 2 of 4: 
System.ArgumentException: App.config does not contain credentials information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey or AWSProfileName. 
 at Amazon.Runtime.StoredProfileAWSCredentials..ctor(String profileName, String profilesLocation) 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.b__2() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean fallbackToAnonymous) 

Exception 3 of 4: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY were not set with AWS credentials. 
 at Amazon.Runtime.EnvironmentVariablesAWSCredentials..ctor() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.b__3() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean fallbackToAnonymous) 

Exception 4 of 4: 
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to reach credentials server 
 at Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetContents(Uri uri) 
 at Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.d__0.MoveNext() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.InstanceProfileAWSCredentials.GetFirstRole() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.b__4() 
 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean fallbackToAnonymous) 


 at Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean fallbackToAnonymous) 
 at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client..ctor(RegionEndpoint region) 
 at SRC_XRay_Sync_Application.MainWindow.startUpload()
```

Answer (score 0):

Profiles in the NET SDK Store are per user/machine. To quote the documentation:

> The credentials in the SDK Store are encrypted, and the SDK Store is
>   in the user's home directory, which limits the risk of accidentally
>   exposing your credentials.

On your production machine, you should be creating a profile in the same way, or since you are unlikely on such a machine to have Visual Studio installed, using AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell.

If security is not a concern, you could put the credentials file directly in the user's home directory in plaintext or specify the location of the credentials file. Naturally this is not recommended as you're exposing your AWS secret to potential compromise.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK.Core"/>
  </configSections>
  <aws profileName="production" profilesLocation="C:\aws_service_credentials\mycredentials"/>
</configuration>
```

Finally if the production machine is in EC2, I would argue that you would be much better off using temporary credentials, instance profiles and IAM roles. This avoids the whole hassle of trying to get credentials securely onto the machines.